# My on change jQuery event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The value of InterMap and interDetailMap are coming from the backend. I have tried many ways to get the selected option but my JQuery change event isn't working.
I think there might be some issue with the sequence of script tags or maybe jquery tags but I cannot understand what's going wrong.

What I want to implement is that when I select Broker then my intermediary name field  values will come from the backend and when I select Outsource then my name dropdown should convert into text input field and all the other fields should convert into empty text fields.

```js
$('#intermediary_type').on('change', function() {
  var selectedType = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
  //var selectedType = document.getElementById("intermediary_type");
  console.log(selectedType);

  //var interMap = ${interMap};
  document.getElementById("intermediary_name").innerHTML = "";
  //var nameList = interMap[selectedType.value];
  //const select="--Select--";
  if (selectedType == "Broker") {
    var drop = "<select class='form-control' id='intermediary_name' name='intermediary_name'></select>"
    $("#intermediary_name").replaceWith(drop);
    $("#intermediary_name").append("<option value=''> --Select---- </option>");
    for (var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
      $("#intermediary_name").append("<option value='" + nameList[i] + "'>" + nameList[i] + "</option>");
    }
    document.getElementById("int_spoc_name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_emailid").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_phonenumber").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_address").value = "";
    $("#intermediary_name").trigger("change");
    $('#intermediary_name').on('change', function() {
      var y = document.getElementById("intermediary_name");
      var interDetailMap = ${interDetailMap};
      var interDetail = interDetailMap[y.value];

      document.getElementById("int_spoc_name").value = interDetail["intSpocName"];
      document.getElementById("int_emailid").value = interDetail["intermediaryMail"];
      document.getElementById("int_phonenumber").value = interDetail["intermediaryMobile"];
      document.getElementById("int_address").value = interDetail["intermediaryAddress"];
      //$("#intermediary_name").append();
    })
  }

  if (selectedType == "Outsource") {
    var txt = "<input type='text' maxlength=50 class='form-control text-alphanumeric-field-alignment' id='intermediary_name' name='intermediary_name'>"
    $("#intermediary_name").replaceWith(txt);
    document.getElementById("intermediary_name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_spoc_name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_emailid").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_phonenumber").value = "";
    document.getElementById("int_address").value = "";
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="h2"> Intermediary Details</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-5 ">
      <label class="field" for="sel1">Type <span
                        style="color: red; font-size: large;">*</span></label>
      <select name="intermediary_type" class="form-control" id="intermediary_type" required>
        <option selected disabled>Select</option>
        <option value="">Broker</option>
        <option value="">Field Functionary</option>
        <option value="">Outsource</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-5 ">
      <label class="field" for="sel1">Name </label>
      <select name="intermediary_name" class="form-control" id="intermediary_name" required>
        <option selected disabled>Select</option>

      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3  mb-5">
      <label for="" class="form-label field">Spoc Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="spoc_name" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="int_spoc_name" aria-label="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3  mb-5">
      <label for="" class="form-label field">Email ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="int_emailid" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="int_emailid" aria-label="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3  mb-5">
      <label for="inputBank_Branch_Address" class="form-label field">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="int_phonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="int_phonenumber" aria-label="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3  mb-5">
      <label for="inputBank_Branch_Address" class="form-label field">Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="int_address" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="int_address" aria-label="" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, you can not use the same ID twice, as you are currently doing.

Comment: I changes the ID's but it still isn't working

Comment: If you use jQuery, why `getElementById()` then? You can use selectors instead of ids.

Comment: Also you got a syntax error while declaring the `interDetailMap` variable.

Comment: Don't define an `on()` event handler inside another event handler.